# Symfony 2.0.6 FOS UserBundle remains in login page

Tags: apache, session, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have two dev environments: one using free MAMP and the other installed MySQL and configured PHP in MacOS Lion.
In the MAMP environment everything is working, however, in the other one it is not. What happens is that when I try to login the browser stays in the same page.

The PHPSESSID is received. 
The path set in php.ini entry "session.save_path" is writable (since it rights when I try to login). And "session.auto_start" is set to "0" (I tried it to set to "1" but then I get an error stating that a session is already started and the start_session() function was ignored)

Any idea what must be causing this? I can post my configurations and code if you think it would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Accidentally updated symfony to version 2.0.12 and the FOS UserBundle to latest version. Because of this, the login form needed the parameter "_csrf_token"